# How find package in CMake with a custom path for OpenCV framework in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv, cmake

I have CMake 3.0 and my own iOS project in C++ that use OpenCV as dependency. That project generate a group of libraries loaded by and application project.

In my CMake, I try to look for OpenCV dependency, It automatically in windows and linux, but in Android & iOS I have to set the correct package. With Android, setting ${OpenCV_dir}/sdk/native/jni works property with this code:

```
SET(OpenCV_DIR NOT_FOUND CACHE PATH "Path to use OpenCV")
IF(OpenCV_DIR STREQUAL NOT_FOUND)
  FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV PATHS ${OpenCV_DIR})
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "--***-- Warning: Install and configure path to prebuilt OpenCVConfig.cmake")
ENDIF()
```

In iOS, this doesnt work. I usually create project Xcode project WITHOUT find OpenCV and then I drag and drop the framework and configure manually variable Framework Search Path with a custom path, in

```
/Users/Piperoman/Libraries/opencv2.4.9IOS
```

but using the CMake code doesnt find it.

What is the problem locating the framework?

Comment: Did you try adding `/Users/Piperoman/Libraries/` to [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html?highlight=cmake_prefix_path), which is used by `FIND_XXX()`?

Comment: First FIND_XXX() I get the error:
Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Trying to add SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} /Users/Piperoman/Libraries/) do nothing, the error is the same

Comment: First, CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is empty by default, and it is a single path not a list, so you should set it directly: `SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /Users/Piperoman/Libraries/)`

Second, I think it is very likely that you should use `/Users/Piperoman/Libraries/opencv2.4.9IOS` for `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. As stated in cmake docs, cmake looks fir directories like `include/` and `lib/` under `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`

Comment: SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH/Users/Piperoman/Libraries/opencv2.4.9IOS/) didn't work. set(OpenCVDID /Users/Piperoman/Libraries/opencv2.4.9IOS) neither. Inside I only have opencv2.framework and CMake seems no detect. With Android native, I put the Opencv.Cmake dir and works perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the problem locating the framework?

`find_package` looking for the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file which doesn't exist in framework directory, i.e. OpenCV iOS simply is not designed so.

You can verify it by:

```
> wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/3.0.0/opencv2.framework.zip
> unzip opencv2.framework.zip
> find opencv2.framework -type f -name "*.cmake"
# nothing found
```

Compare to Android:

```
> wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/3.0.0/OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk-1.zip
> unzip OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk-1.zip
> find OpenCV-android-sdk -type f -name "*.cmake"
...
OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCVConfig.cmake
...
```

If you're looking for CMake friendly solution you can try [Hunter](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter) package manager, see [pkg.opencv](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/wiki/pkg.opencv):

```
hunter_add_package(OpenCV)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(... PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

### Hunter iOS instructions

Since version [3.5](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/release/3.5.html#platforms) CMake supports installation of universal (multiarch, device + simulator) iOS libraries (see [CMAKE_IOS_INSTALL_COMBINED](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_IOS_INSTALL_COMBINED.html)).

Hunter use this feature since version [0.13.1](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/releases/tag/v0.13.1).

Choose [iOS toolchain](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter#toolchain-id), e.g. ios-8-2:

```
> git clone https://github.com/ruslo/polly
> ls polly/ios-8-2.cmake
```

CMakeLists.txt will [looks like this](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter#first-step):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

include("cmake/HunterGate.cmake")
HunterGate(
    URL "https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/archive/v0.13.1.tar.gz"
    SHA1 "bd7711df37a53134e642220d2f649a69cb34dde3"
)

project(TestOpenCV)

hunter_add_package(OpenCV)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Build it:

```
> cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/.../polly/ios-8-2.cmake -GXcode
> cmake --build _builds --config Release
```

Alternatively you can use [build.py](https://github.com/ruslo/polly#buildpy) script to pick toolchain and generator:

```
> git clone https://github.com/ruslo/polly
> export PATH=`pwd`/polly/bin:$PATH
> which build.py
```

Build it (build.py variant):

```
> build.py --toolchain ios-8-2 --verbose --config Release
```

Comment: After download the Hunter in "/Users/Piperoman/Librerias/hunter-master/"

I got: "Unknown CMake command "hunter_add_package" "

I tried to add it manually:
SET(HUNTER_BINARY_DIR "/Users/Piperoman/Librerias/hunter-master/")
  INCLUDE(${HUNTER_BINARY_DIR}cmake/Hunter)
  option(HUNTER_ENABLED "Enable Hunter package manager" ON)

I cannot find in the wiki intructions to add propertly on my project, do you know where they are?

Comment: Mmmh, I cannot test it right now, its failing my ios toolchain. Its a little bit complicated method, but thanks for the effort. If nobody answer something easier, I will give you the Bounty.

I have a little repository with cmake toolchains and macros : https://bitbucket.org/piperoman/cmakesupport, I use it as submodule in my projects, I will try to integrate hunter as submodule working automatically if I archieve to work successfully with it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My project is configured to generate a XCode project with my own toolchain (From submodule cmakesupport), and when configure Cmake, HunterGate launch error C compiler was not found (https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/wiki/error.abi.detection.failure) I assume its a problem with my current configuration. I will try with a new simple project to make it work. With submodule i mean, use huntergate in my tool.